# Change location of UIView within captureOutput

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, avfoundation

Currently I have an AVCaptureSession running in my Swift app and I have a UIView with a CGRect that I want to move around over the camera feed. I have been trying to update the location of the UIView's frame by changing the coordinates in the captureOutput function but as I change them they are not updating. What is the proper way to change the location of UIView so that it updates on the fly?

Here's the section of code where the capture session is made:

```
class CameraViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
```

{

```
@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIImageView!
var rectangleView : UIView!
var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var rect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 50, height: 50)
var xCoord: Float = 0.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //---editing rectangle view---
    rectangleView = UIView()
    rectangleView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hue: 0.2444, saturation: 1, brightness: 0.96, alpha: 1).cgColor
    rectangleView.layer.borderWidth = 50;
    rectangleView.tag = 1
    self.view.addSubview(rectangleView)
    //----------------------------


    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()
    do{
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    }catch{
        print("Error finding back Camera")
    }
    var error : NSError?

    if (error == nil && (captureSession?.canAddInput(input))!)
    {
        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "string buffer delegate"))

        if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(dataOutput))!
        {

            captureSession?.addOutput(dataOutput)
            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            //                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
            self.view.bringSubview(toFront: rectangleView)
            previewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
            rectangleView.frame = rect
            captureSession?.startRunning()

        }
    }
}
```

Here's the captureOutput function:
the setY method is an extension to the UIView class that changes the y coordinate of the frame.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer!)
    let x = rectangleView.frame.origin.x
    let y = rectangleView.frame.origin.y - 1
    let height = rectangleView.frame.size.height
    let width = rectangleView.frame.size.width

    rectangleView.setY(y: y)

    print(rectangleView.frame.origin.y)

    //*** Making UIImage out of pixelBuffer ****
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
    let pixelBufferWidth = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer!))
    let pixelBufferHeight = CGFloat(CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer!))
    let imageRect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: pixelBufferWidth, height: pixelBufferHeight)
    let ciContext = CIContext.init()
    let cgimage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect )
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage!)
    //******************************************



}
```

Thanks for the help,

-nfarrell

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Yup I'll edit it now.

Comment: Have you tried calling the `setY(y:)` method on the main thread? `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.rectangleView.setY(y: y) }`. (I'm assuming you've tested the `setY` method outside of this method and confirmed that it works as expected)

Comment: Excellent advice man thanks for the fix. I'm new to stackoverflow. Is there anyway I could give you an up vote or something for helping me out?

Comment: I'll add my comment as an answer, and you can accept it and upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `setY(y:)` method on the main thread, since it's manipulating the UI:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.rectangleView.setY(y: y)
}
```